# Filter Array of Objects by Group based on property value - data from JSON response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have the json data which I want to make the table based on json response.I want group the value based on SalesStage .In group 1 have the data only for `Qualified ,Proposal Submitted and Negotiation & Contracting`.In group 2 have the only data `Closed Won`,In group 3 `Closed lost,Deferred` and in group 4 `Identified,QO under Evaluation`

```
[{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 24, pipelinevalue: 3140000},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 22, pipelinevalue: 1303344},
 {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 554000},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 12, pipelinevalue: 4516510},
 {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 60000},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 5, pipelinevalue: 977914},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 480000},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 5, pipelinevalue: 1084400},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 30, pipelinevalue: 11725971},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 7, pipelinevalue: 937536},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Lost", count: 91, pipelinevalue: 9799084},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Deferred Opportunity", count: 26, pipelinevalue: 1858042},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Deferred Opportunity", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 777000}]
```

Expected output
group1=

```
[{Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 60000},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 480000},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 5, pipelinevalue: 1084400},
 {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 554000},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 5, pipelinevalue: 977914}]

group2=[{Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 30, pipelinevalue: 11725971},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 7, pipelinevalue: 937536}] 
 
 group3=[{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Lost", count: 91, pipelinevalue: 9799084},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Deferred Opportunity", count: 26, pipelinevalue: 1858042},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Deferred Opportunity", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 777000}]
 
 group4=[{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 24, pipelinevalue: 3140000},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 22, pipelinevalue: 1303344}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` like this:

```js
let data = [{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 24, pipelinevalue: 3140000},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 22, pipelinevalue: 1303344},
 {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 554000},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 12, pipelinevalue: 4516510},
 {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 60000},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 5, pipelinevalue: 977914},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 480000},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 5, pipelinevalue: 1084400},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 30, pipelinevalue: 11725971},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 7, pipelinevalue: 937536},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Lost", count: 91, pipelinevalue: 9799084},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Deferred Opportunity", count: 26, pipelinevalue: 1858042},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Deferred Opportunity", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 777000}]
 
 let group1 = data.filter(obj => ['Qualified' ,'Proposal Submitted','Negotiation & Contracting'].includes(obj.SalesStage))
 console.log('group1')
 console.log(group1)
 
  let group2 = data.filter(obj => obj.SalesStage == 'Closed Won')
  console.log('group2')
 console.log(group2)
 
  let group3 = data.filter(obj => ['Closed Lost','Deferred Opportunity'].includes(obj.SalesStage))
  console.log('group3')
 console.log(group3)
 
  let group4 = data.filter(obj => ['Identified','QO under Evaluation'].includes(obj.SalesStage))
  console.log('group4')
 console.log(group4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array of object and push the group into the corresponding group based on the condition.

```js
let groups = [{Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 24, pipelinevalue: 3140000},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Identified", count: 22, pipelinevalue: 1303344},
 {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 2, pipelinevalue: 554000},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 12, pipelinevalue: 4516510},
 {Geo: "NSU", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 60000},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Proposal Submitted", count: 5, pipelinevalue: 977914},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 1, pipelinevalue: 480000},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Qualified", count: 5, pipelinevalue: 1084400},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 30, pipelinevalue: 11725971},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Won", count: 7, pipelinevalue: 937536},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Closed Lost", count: 91, pipelinevalue: 9799084},
 {Geo: "US East", SalesStage: "Deferred Opportunity", count: 26, pipelinevalue: 1858042},
 {Geo: "US West", SalesStage: "Deferred Opportunity", count: 3, pipelinevalue: 777000}];

  let group1 = [];
  let group2 = [];
  let group3 = [];
  let group4 = [];

  groups.forEach(group => {
    if (['Qualified', 'Proposal Submitted', 'Negotiation', 'Contracting'].includes(group.SalesStage)) {
      group1.push(group);
    } else if (group.SalesStage === 'Closed Won') {
      group2.push(group);
    } else if (['Closed Lost', 'Deferred Opportunity'].includes(group.SalesStage)) {
      group3.push(group);
    } else if (['Identified', 'QO under Evaluation'].includes(group.SalesStage)) {
      group4.push(group)
    }});

  console.log(group1);
  console.log(group2);
  console.log(group3);
  console.log(group4);
```